# What is best way to manage impala resource in multi-tenant Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, multi-tenant, cloudera, impala

As per Impala, The Llama support code is removed entirely in Impala 2.8 and higher. It means that Impala resources are not managed by Yarn.

What is best way to handle resource management in multi-tenant Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Creating esource pools could be solution. https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_howto_rm.html